# Need to know about c++ strchr function and how it works

Tags: c, strchr

I want to know about `strchr` function in C++.

For example:

```
realm=strchr(name,'@');
```

What is the meaning for this line?

Comment: You have consulted the [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr), right?

Comment: This is *not* C++, it's pure C.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/).

Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of character in the C string str.

The terminating null-character is considered part of the C string. Therefore, it can also be located to retrieve a pointer to the end of a string.

```
/* strchr example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Looking for the 's' character in \"%s\"...\n",str);
  pch=strchr(str,'s');
  while (pch!=NULL)
  {
    printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
    pch=strchr(pch+1,'s');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

will produce output

```
Looking for the 's' character in "This is a sample string"...
found at 4
found at 7
found at 11
found at 18
```

Answer (score 2):

[www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) is a very usable site for C++ help. Such as explaining functions.

For [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/):

> Locate first occurrence of character in string Returns a pointer to
>   the first occurrence of character in the C string str.
>
> The terminating null-character is considered part of the C string.
>   Therefore, it can also be located to retrieve a pointer to the end of
>   a string.

```
char* name = "hi@hello.com";
char* realm = strchr(name,'@');

//realm will point to "@hello.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who are looking here for source code/implementation:

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    while (*s != (char)c)
        if (!*s++)
            return 0;
    return (char *)s;
}
```

(origin: http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/strchr)